# Java timer error exception

Tags: java

I have a strange error when executing a timertask, what cause it?

```
public void tick(long milliseconds) {
ctimer = new Timer();
ctimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
    System.out.println("sec"+sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition()/1000000);           }
}, 0, milliseconds);
}
```

Error message from command prompt:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at MidiTest$1.run(miditest.java:244)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet that `sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition()` returns a `Long` and it's null. The problem happens because autoboxing/unboxing cannot handle nulls.

#### edit

Autoboxing is when java transforms a primitive type to it's object wrapper, for example `long` to `Long`. You can read more about this feature in these [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

There's no recipe to fix this, as it depends on what you want to do. Probably you can replace the body of `run()` with

```
long position = 0;
if( sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition() != null ) {
    position = sequencer.getMicrosecondPosition();
}

System.out.println("sec" + position/1000000);
```

which will default the position to 0 if getMicrosecondPosition() is null

Comment: yes you are right on it, what is autoboxing? How do I fix it?